# What's the best place for python classes in a Django project?

Tags: django

It might sound trivial, but I'd like to know where I am supposed put my python classes (not from `Model`)?

I mean, my model classes are defined in `myapp/models.py` but I want, for example, use a syndication feed framework to write a simple feed. [The doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/syndication/) says that I need to write a Feed class but...  Where should I put the code? Which path and file? I'd like to stick to the default Django directory structure.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are free to put it where you want.

example:

```
project
  myapp 
     views.py
     models.py
     feeds.py
```

Then you can import you're feeds module by using import.

from project.myapp.feeds import *

Making directory is better when you deal with a lot of file. For example:

```
project
    myapp
      models.py
      views.py
      extras
        feeds.py
        sitemaps.py
```

I suggest you to read this: [Python Modules: Packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

Comment: So... there is no any Django convention for it? If I have several classes, should I make a "classes" folder under myapp dir? 

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest not, it makes lot of confusion.

Is cleaner to have this:
project.myapp.feeds

than

project.myapp.classed.feeds

Eventually you can do this:

project.myapp.extras.feeds

project
   myapp
     extras 
       feed

Answer (score 4):

For feed-related classes, it's conventional to place them in a module called `feeds` in the appropriate application module. For example, if you have a blog with an RSS feed, your project structure would look like this:

```
project/
    blog/
        __init__.py
        feeds.py
        models.py
        views.py
```

*In general*, for other non-model classes, you can put them anywhere you want (as noted by Andrea Di Persio). Typically you place them as a module in the appropriate application package. For general-use classes, I usually create a package called `lib` that contains general classes and functions, like so:

```
project/
    blog/
        __init__.py
        feeds.py
        models.py
        other_stuff.py
        views.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        things.py
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Models.py
```

is the best place for your class, because models have access to data stored in the database.